# How to run config-pin from a docker container on a Beaglebone black?

Tags: node.js, docker, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I am dockerizing my beaglebone sw. I have pretty much completed the process, but there is still one thing I cannot manage to run.

I use the `FROM balenalib/beaglebone-black-alpine-node:12` image.

Prior to operate the CANbus, I must issue the following commands:

```
config-pin p9.19 can
config-pin p9.20 can
/sbin/ip link set can1 up type can bitrate 250000
```

The point is that config-pin is outside the container.

What's the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'config-pin is outside the container'? The config-pin script? Or do you mean that you don't have access to the pins?

Comment: I mean the exec file config-pin is in the /usr/bin of the beaglebone installation and not in the alpine installation in my container

Answer (score 1):

I guess `config-pin` use `glibc` rather than `muslc` which means it can't execute in `alpine`.

So the suggested solution is:

- **Write a daemon service in host**

  This daemon receive the command from your alpine container, then depends on the command received to call `config-pin` on host to configure your `beaglebone`.
- **Additional, there is a very hacky way to let you execute host's program:**

  (**NOTE**: it requires your container to share all namespace with host, if you can accept this limit, you could have a try)

  ***Minimal example of hacky way:***

  **1.** Setup `/root/20210903/run.sh` on host:

  ```
  root@shubuntu1:~/20210903# cat /root/20210903/run.sh
  echo "helloworld"
  ```

  **2.** Run the alpine container to call `run.sh`:

  ```
  root@shubuntu1:~/20210903# docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host balenalib/beaglebone-black-alpine-node:12 /bin/sh
  Here are a few details about this Docker image (For more information please visit https://www.balena.io/docs/reference/base-images/base-images/):
  Architecture: ARM v7
  OS: Alpine Linux 3.12
  Variant: run variant
  Default variable(s): UDEV=off
  The following software stack is preinstalled:
  Node.js v12.19.1, Yarn v1.22.4
  Extra features:
  - Easy way to install packages with `install_packages <package-name>` command
  - Run anywhere with cross-build feature  (for ARM only)
  - Keep the container idling with `balena-idle` command
  - Show base image details with `balena-info` command
  / # chroot /host bash /root/20210903/run.sh
  helloworld
  / # cat /etc/issue
  Welcome to Alpine Linux 3.12
  Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
  / # chroot /host cat /etc/issue
  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l
  / #
  ```

You could see with `# chroot /host bash /root/20210903/run.sh`, we successfully called the script on host. But it's really hacky, just for your reference.